# xtify GCM doesn't work anymore

Tags: null, google-cloud-messaging, xtify

A few months ago I implemented xtify SDK for Android GCM and it used to work well (the instruction `XtifySDK.getXidKey(getApplicationContext())` returned a xid, but now it doesn't work anymore and I didn't make any changes since then.

I realized the SDK was updated (I was using 2.3) so I made everything since the beginning (created a new Google GCM application (server key without associated IPs); created a new app key in xtify console (development key), added the necessary info in manifest and the libraries.

I've implemented:

```
public class XtifyNotifier extends XtifyBroadcastReceiver
{ 
    final String XTIFY_APP_KEY = //app key in console
    final String SENDER_ID = //project number in google application

    protected void onRegistered(Context arg0)
    { //applicationContext
       XtifySDK.start(arg0, XTIFY_APP_KEY, SENDER_ID);

       String xid = XtifySDK.getXidKey(arg0); //and this is the problem, it returns always null
       .....
    }
}
```

The target is Google APIs (level 8) and I have a Google account configured in the phone. I tried again the sample but it still doesn't work.

Does anyone know about some kind of changes or limitations in the SDK?

Comment: I noticed that you are calling XtifySDK.start in onRegistered, it should only be called from your main activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried the sample app and replaced the project number and appKey and still didn't work, then its most likely an issue with your Google API account, did you changed your Google password recently? this could invalidate your Google API key, also make sure you enabled GCM for your API key (go to the Services tab and enable Google Cloud Messaging for Android).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. No, I haven't changed password in google account. I tried again with other account (and created other google application) but the result is the same.  The result is also the same if I call XtifySDK.start on Main Activity